# Display and hide Textfield programmatically for iPhone/Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm trying to create a custom editor for my UIViewController. It was suggested that I hide the textfields until the user presses the Edit key. How do you do this programmatically?

In other words when the user hits 'Edit' I would like the label to disappear and the Textfield to appear.

Thanks,

Comment: I put sample code in the answer. Check back. Both answers below are good ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `hidden` property for quickly turning something visible or invisible.

```
self.widget1.hidden = YES;
self.widget2.hidden = NO;
```

Another option is to set alpha to 0 to hide and 1 to show. This is beneficial if you want to have an animation fade the widgets in and out for a smooth transition.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
self.widget1.alpha = 0;
self.widget2.alpha = 1;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the `hidden` property.

```
label.hidden = YES;
textField.hidden = NO;
```